# Conceptual Question: Is acceleration due to gravity positive or negative, and if depending on the situation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, acceleration, vectors

So on brilliant.org, I read a problem where they used the kinematic formula $r_y=v_0T-\frac{1}{2}gT^2$, for when $v_0=120 \frac{m}{s}$ and the magnitude of the acceleration due to gravity is $=10\frac{m}{s}$. We were asked to find the time it would take for the arrows to reach the ground assuming it was shot at ground level straight up.  Brilliant did $r_y=0$ and I am unsure whether $r_y$ is the displacement or the distance in the y direction. Anyhow, they got $0=(v_0-\frac{1}{2}gT)T$ and from that I got $T=\frac{2v_0}{g}$ from that question. However, time would be negative if the value of $g$ is negative. Another way to do it, with negative $g$ is to make the max height have a final velocity of $0$ but brilliant did not do it this way.

I know this is a very specific problem, but the questions are not, they are conceptual (so please don't close this post).

To make it clear, my questions are:

1. Is $r_y$ in $r_y=v_0T-\frac{1}{2}gT^2$ the displacement or the distance of the projectile in the y direction.
2. When do I use positive $g$ and when do I use negative $g$ and can I just apply positive $g$ and a displacement of zero in a kinematic problem where the projectile goes all the way up and all the way down?
3. Can one single kinematic equation be used to find time, for a projectile that goes up and then falls back down, with acceleration of $g$ and a known velocity $v_0$, without breaking it into two motions (one up and one down), with the final velocity of the first motion equal to $0$ and the initial velocity of the second motion equal to $0$, I guess this is the (i.e.) of all the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Acceleration is a vector, and its direction depends on how you set up your coordinate systems.

For example if you're considering projectile motion, then it's normal to define the $0$ of position as the ground level. It's also normal to define "upwards" as the positive direction of motion: for example we say we throw something upwards at $2 ms^{-1}$, not $-2 ms^{-1}$. In this case we say gravity is negative, because it's acting downwards.

However you are equally free to choose your positive direction as downwards. For example if you're dealing with a problem where a particle is released from rest some height above ground level, then you might choose the positive direction to be down. In this case gravity would be positive.

In summary, $g$ can be positive or negative - it depends completely on how you define your coordinates.

Comment: It's the components which depend on the coordinate system, not direction. Direction is fixed in space.

Answer (score 1):

Acceleration is a vector. The *magnitude* of acceleration is a *non*-negative real number, and that is typically what $g$, as a real number, without boldface type, refers to. But a vector also provides for information as to its direction, and this may be as simple as a "positive/negative" distinction, or it may be more complicated.

In this case, you are considering one-dimensional motion, where the direction *is* as simple as positive versus negative. But what is confusing is that in this one-dimensional case, as here, a one-dimensional vector and a real number are mathematically equivalent (in formalese: $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space over itself), and hence often times the two are used interchangeably, creating a mess for those not initiate, and thus one is tempted to equivocate $g$ not to be the magnitude of the (one-dimensional) acceleration vector but rather its sole vector component, and these are two very different things, and hence this confusion.

To that end, what I'd suggest is the answer is to buck the convention and call it an honest vector. Write $\mathbf{g}$ for your gravitational acceleration in boldface type, even though this is 1D. This is a vector, and you denote its *sole* component $g_x$, or $g_y$ if you prefer. That is,

$$\mathbf{g} = \langle g_y \rangle$$

as in typical vector component notation, but with only that one vector component. That's not a joke; this notation's entirely reasonable. The magnitude of the one-dimensional vector $\mathbf{g}$ is $g$, and $g = |g_y|$. The associated direction information is in the sign of $g_y$ (*not* $g$): either "+" or "-".

Which *physical* direction a "+" or "-" sign of $g_y$ corresponds to depends on how you have set up your coordinate system. *If* you take the sole axis as having its positive direction representing "upwards", then this *vector component* $g_y$ is negative: $g_y = -g$. If you take it as representing "downwards", then it is positive: $g_y = g$. The same will also go with all your other one-dimensional vectors, such as position ($\mathbf{r}$ with sole component $r_y$, and likewise). These all have to consistently follow the same conventions.

So this is how we apply it to this problem. The kinematic equation looks like

$$\mathbf{r}(t) := \mathbf{v}_0 t + \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{a}t^2$$

Here, these are *one*-dimensional vectors, with single vector component forms:

$$\mathbf{v}_0 = \langle v_{0_y} \rangle$$

and

$$\mathbf{g} = \langle g_y \rangle$$

And thus we get, for the *single component*,

$$r_y(t) = v_{0_y} t + \frac{1}{2} g_y t^2$$

and now it is *$g_y$*, *not* $g$, which is negative:

$$g_y = -g$$

thus

$$r_y(t) = v_{0_y} t - \frac{1}{2} gt^2$$

which is the expression you give. $g$, the *magnitude* of $\mathbf{g}$, *is positive*.

That said, due to the above easy conflation between a one-dimensional real vector and a real number, $g$ *can* sometimes get used for what I have called $g_y$. The point is that you have to keep these things separate to keep it clear.

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to the correct answer of @Allure, note that the framers of the question in the original post have failed to choose a particular direction as positive.  Instead, they have defined an *upward velocity as positive*, and at the same time defined a *downward acceleration as also positive*.

They then try to extricate themselves from this self-created maze by creating a new kinematic equation that exists only in the context of the conflicting definitions.  Every other physics text has something along the lines of:
$$d=ut+\frac{at^2}{2}$$Using this equation, along with something along the lines of: $$\text{Up is (arbitrarily) positive.}$$ $$\text{u is }120 \text{ m/s }\text{ upward, therefore } u = 120 \text{ m/s }$$ $$\text{g is 10 m/s}^2\text{downward, therefore }a=-10 m/s^2$$ will produce the correct answer.